# JavaScript - Getting specific 9 character value from string by regex

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I'm trying to retrieve a 9 number long value from a string.

The strings will never have the same content but there will always be a group of numbers 9 characters in length that I'm trying to get into a variable.

https://jsbin.com/gabuhilexu/edit?js,console

I have tried a few samples of regex

```
var first = "https://www.wrike.com/open.htm?id=119464511";
var second = "119464511: Hello world";
var third = "Hello world: 119464511 - Testing";

var broken = first.split('https://www.wrike.com/open.htm?id=');

var reg = /([^0-9])(?:11(1\d)1(\d{4}))([^0-9])/g;

console.log(first.split(reg));
console.log(reg.test(second));
```

There are two examples of how the strings are currently being delivered and I'm trying to get the `119464511` value into a variable.

Comment: If it's just a nine digit number can't you just match `/\d{9}/`?

Comment: You can just use: `/\b\d{9}\b/`

Comment: Or matching the 1's `\b11\d{5}11\b`

Comment: The numbers may not always be at the start or the end, may never be 1's either.

Comment: What do you mean they may never be ones? That's confusing when you say you're trying to get `119464511` which contains 4 ones.

Comment: I think they mean that the leading and trailing `11` are random and not part of the pattern, but if that's true, the RegEx they tried is flagrantly incorrect.

Comment: Do you need `s.match(/\b\d{9}\b/g)`? Or do you want `/(?:^|\D)(\d{9})(?!\d)/g` (you need to grab Group 1 here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RegEx you've tried is problematic for a number of reasons.

- Firstly, it uses a non-capturing group; this effectively negates
  everything you're searching for.
- Secondly, it requires that the first
  character be non-numeric, which doesn't hold for the example you've
  stored in the variable `second`.
- Thirdly, it is hard-coded to search for several `1`s within the non-capturing group, but because the `id` is effectively random (as you indicated), this won't work for the vast majority of values.

To follow up on the third bullet point, the RegEx you provided will match only values that fit the following pattern: `A111#1####A`, where `A` represents any non-numeric character, and `1` is hard-coded. The `#` are the only places where you search for any digit in the range `0-9`.

If you're just trying to obtain the numbers, then you can use a simple RegEx of `/\d{9}/g`, which finds any and all groups of 9 numeric characters within the string you provide.